# What does the cry "kon" mean?

Tags: inari-konkon-koi-iroha

In the end of episode 9, Inari's assigned apprentice familiar Kon the two guardian foxes of Uka-sama start crying the sound "kon" and soon the other foxes around Inari shrine respond, gathering as blue magic fires on the road up the mountain.

[image] [image]

Is this like dog's barking is transcribed as "woof" but in fox version? Or is it a name of some higher power they were calling?

Comment: For more information, see [this documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE).

Comment: @senshin come on, I was trying to avoid phrasing the question like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how Japanese interpret phonetically the cries of foxes, the english equivalent to "woof". There's no special meaning in the title.